# Simpler alternative libs to Reactive? (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, architecture, frp

I'm learning Haskell, and trying to write some event-driven programs.

The following code is from the tutorial: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/OpenGLTutorial2

```
main = do
  (progname,_) <- getArgsAndInitialize
  initialDisplayMode $= [DoubleBuffered]
  createWindow "Hello World"
  reshapeCallback $= Just reshape
  angle <- newIORef (0.0::GLfloat)          -- 1
  delta <- newIORef (0.1::GLfloat)          -- 2
  position <- newIORef (0.0::GLfloat, 0.0)  -- 3
  keyboardMouseCallback $= Just (keyboardMouse delta position)
  idleCallback $= Just (idle angle delta)
  displayCallback $= (display angle position)
  mainLoop
```

The states are stored in `IORef`s, which makes it looks just like imperative language.

I'v heard that there are APIs other than this `Graphics.UI.GLUT`, (e.g. `Reactive`), but it looks very complicated.

My approach is that the lib provide a function `runEventHandler`, and the user writes a `handler` that accepts list of `Event`s and convert them to `IO ()`.

```
handler :: [Event] -> IO ()
runEventHandler :: ( [Event] -> IO () ) -> IO ()
```

And the `main` function should look like:

```
main = runEventHandler handler
```

Is there such libs?

I am currently implementing one using multi-threading, but I'm worrying that it might be poor in performance ...

Comment: AFAIK Reactive is deprecated. I know that netwire and reactive-banana are relatively up to date, though I don't know whether you would consider them _easier_. As for GUI applications, there's reactive-banana-wx, see example: https://github.com/HeinrichApfelmus/reactive-banana/blob/master/reactive-banana-wx/src/Asteroids.hs

Comment: [Reactive Banana](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Reactive-banana) is a FRP framework for declaring these dependencies. You can also look at something like [Yampa](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Yampa) which allows you to declare  the dependencies as you gave. I don't know whether Yampa also has bindings to GUIs as Reactive Banana does. [Another question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672791/is-functional-gui-programming-possible) might also help you further in terms of reactive programming of GUIs.

Comment: Elerea is supposed to be pretty nice as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the status of current Functional Reactive Programming implementations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341937/whats-the-status-of-current-functional-reactive-programming-implementations)

Comment: The above linked question should answer your concerns.

Comment: Just a food for thoughts: http://dmytrish.wordpress.com/2013/01/12/haskell-opengl-animation-done-right/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[reactive-banana](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana) is a mature library very similar to [reactive](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive). We won't try to reinvent an frp library; instead we'll explore how to integrate reactive-banana into a project for ourselves.

#### The big picture

To use a functional reactive programming library like reactive-banana with OpenGL we will divide the work into 4 parts, 2 of which already exist. We will use the existing GLUT library to interact with OpenGL, and the existing reactive-banana library for an implementation of functional reactive programming. We will provide 2 parts of our own. The first part we will provide is a framework that will connect GLUT to reactive-banana. The second part we will provide is the program that will be written in terms of the frp implementation (reactive-banana) and framework and GLUT types.

Both of the parts that we provide will be written in terms of the reactive-banana frp library. The library has two big ideas, `Event t a` and `Behavior t a`. `Event t a` represents events carrying data of type `a` that occur at different points in time. `Behavior t a` represents a time varying value of type `a` that is defined at all points in time. The `t` type argument we are required by the type system to preserve but otherwise ignore.

Most of the interface to `Event` and `Behavior` are hidden in their instances. `Event` is a `Functor` - we can `fmap` or `<$>` a function over the values of any `Event`.

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Event t a -> Event t b
```

`Behavior` is both `Applicative` and a `Functor`. We can `fmap` or `<$>` a function over all the values a `Behavior` takes on, can provide new constant unchanging values with `pure`, and calculate new `Behavior`s with `<*>`.

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> Behavior t a -> Behavior t b
pure :: a -> Behavior t a
<*> :: Behavior t (a -> b) -> Behavior t a -> Behavior t b
```

There are a few [other functions provided by reactive-banana](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-0.8.0.2/docs/Reactive-Banana-Combinators.html) that provide functionality that can't be represented in terms of base typeclasses. These introduce statefulness, combine `Event`s together, and convert between `Event`s and `Behavior`s.

State is introduced by `accumE` which takes an initial value and an `Event` of changes from the previous value to a new value and produces an `Event` of the new values. `accumB` produces a `Behavior` instead

```
accumE :: a -> Event t (a -> a) -> Event t a
accumB :: a -> Event t (a -> a) -> Behavior t a
```

`union` combines two event streams together

```
union :: Event t a -> Event t a -> Event t a
```

`stepper` can convert an `Event` to a `Behavior` holding the most recent value if we provide an initial value so that it is defined at all points in time. `apply` or `<@>` can convert a `Behavior` into an `Event` if we provide a series of `Events` at which to poll the current value of the `Behavior`.

```
stepper :: a -> Event t a -> Behavior t a
<@> :: Behavior t (a -> b) -> Event t a -> Event t b
```

The instances for `Event` and `Behavior` and the 19 functions in [Reactive.Banana.Combinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana-0.8.0.2/docs/Reactive-Banana-Combinators.html) make up the entire interface for functional reactive programming.

Overall, we will need the GLUT library and libraries used by the OpenGL example we are implementing, the reactive-banana library, the reactive-banana exports for making frameworks and the RankNTypes extension, a couple mechanisms for interthread communication, and the ability to read the system clock.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Graphics.UI.GLUT
import Control.Monad

import Reactive.Banana
import Reactive.Banana.Frameworks

import Data.IORef
import Control.Concurrent.MVar

import Data.Time
```

#### The framework interface

Our framework will map the `IO` events from GLUT to reactive-banana `Event`s and `Behavior`s. There are four GLUT events that the example uses - `reshapeCallback`, `keyboardMouseCallback`, `idleCallback`, and `displayCallback`. We will map these to `Event`s and `Behavior`s.

`reshapeCallback` is run when the user resizes the window. As a callback, it required something of the type `type ReshapeCallback = Size -> IO ()`. We will represent this as an `Event t Size`.

`keyboardMouseCallback` is run when the user provides keyboard input, moves the mouse, or clicks a mouse button. As a callback, it required something of the type `type KeyboardMouseCallback = Key -> KeyState -> Modifiers -> Position -> IO ()`. We will represent this as an input with type `Event t KeyboardMouse`, where `KeyboardMouse` bundles together all of the arguments passed to the callback.

```
data KeyboardMouse = KeyboardMouse {
    key :: Key,
    keyState :: KeyState,
    modifiers :: Modifiers,
    pos :: Position
}
```

`idleCallback` is run when time passes. We will represent this as a behavior that tracks the amount of time that has passed, `Behavior t DiffTime`. Because it is a `Behavior` instead of an `Event`, our program won't be able to directly observe time passing. If this isn't desired, we could use an `Event` instead.

Bundling all of the inputs together we get

```
data Inputs t = Inputs {
    keyboardMouse :: Event t KeyboardMouse,    
    time :: Behavior t DiffTime,
    reshape :: Event t Size
}
```

`displayCallback` is different from the other callbacks; it isn't for the input to the program, but instead is for outputting what needs to be displayed. Since GLUT could run this at any time to try to display something on the screen, it makes sense for it to be defined at all points in time. We will represent this output with a `Behavior t DisplayCallback`.

There is one more output we will need - in response to events the example program occasionally produces other IO actions. We will allow the program to raise events to execute arbitrary IO with an `Event t (IO ())`.

Bundling both outputs together we get

```
data Outputs t = Outputs {
    display :: Behavior t DisplayCallback,
    whenIdle :: Event t (IO ())
}
```

Our framework will be invoked by passing it a program with the type `forall t. Inputs t -> Outputs t`. We will define `program` and `reactiveGLUT` in the next two sections.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  (progname,_) <- getArgsAndInitialize
  initialDisplayMode $= [DoubleBuffered]
  createWindow "Hello World"
  reactiveGLUT program
```

#### The program

The program will use reactive-banana to map the `Inputs` to the `Outputs`. To get started porting the tutorial code, we'll remove the `IORef`s from `cubes` and rename `reshape` to `onReshape` since it conflicts with a name from our framework interface.

```
cubes :: GLfloat -> (GLfloat, GLfloat) -> DisplayCallback
cubes a (x',y') = do 
  clear [ColorBuffer]
  loadIdentity
  translate $ Vector3 x' y' 0
  preservingMatrix $ do
    rotate a $ Vector3 0 0 1
    scale 0.7 0.7 (0.7::GLfloat)
    forM_ (points 7) $ \(x,y,z) -> preservingMatrix $ do
      color $ Color3 ((x+1)/2) ((y+1)/2) ((z+1)/2)
      translate $ Vector3 x y z
      cube 0.1
  swapBuffers

onReshape :: ReshapeCallback
onReshape size = do 
  viewport $= (Position 0 0, size)
```

`keyboardMouse` will be completely replaced by `positionChange` and `angleSpeedChange`. These convert a `KeyboardMouse` event into a change to make to either the position or the speed the cubes are rotating. When no change is needed for an event, they return `Nothing`.

```
positionChange :: Fractional a => KeyboardMouse -> Maybe ((a, a) -> (a, a))
positionChange (KeyboardMouse (SpecialKey k) Down _ _) = case k of
  KeyLeft  -> Just $ \(x,y) -> (x-0.1,y)
  KeyRight -> Just $ \(x,y) -> (x+0.1,y)
  KeyUp    -> Just $ \(x,y) -> (x,y+0.1)
  KeyDown  -> Just $ \(x,y) -> (x,y-0.1)
  _        -> Nothing
positionChange _ = Nothing

angleSpeedChange :: Num a => KeyboardMouse -> Maybe (a -> a)
angleSpeedChange (KeyboardMouse (Char c) Down _ _) = case c of
  ' ' -> Just negate
  '+' -> Just (+1)
  '-' -> Just (subtract 1)
  _   -> Nothing
angleSpeedChange _ = Nothing
```

Calculating the position is fairly easy, we accumulate the changes from the keyboard inputs. `filterJust :: Event t (Maybe a) -> Event t a` throws out the events that we weren't interested in.

```
positionB :: Fractional a => Inputs t -> Behavior t (a, a)
positionB = accumB (0.0, 0.0) . filterJust . fmap positionChange . keyboardMouse
```

We'll calculate the angle of the rotating cubes a bit differently. We'll remember the time and angle when the speed changes, apply a function that calculates the difference in angle to the difference in times, and add that to the initial angle.

```
angleCalculation :: (Num a, Num b) => a -> b -> (a -> b) -> a -> b
angleCalculation a0 b0 f a1 = f (a1 - a0) + b0
```

Calculating the `angle` is a bit more difficult. First we compute an event, `angleF :: Event t (DiffTime -> GLfloat)`, holding a function from a difference between times to a difference between angles. We lift and apply our `angleCalculation` to the current `time` and `angle`, and poll that at each occurrence of the `angleF` event. We convert the polled function into a `Behavior` with `stepper` and apply it to the current `time`.

```
angleB :: Fractional a => Inputs t -> Behavior t a
angleB inputs = angle
    where
        initialSpeed = 2
        angleSpeed = accumE initialSpeed . filterJust . fmap angleSpeedChange . keyboardMouse $ inputs
        scaleSpeed x y = 10 * x * realToFrac y
        angleF = scaleSpeed <$> angleSpeed
        angleSteps = (angleCalculation <$> time inputs <*> angle) <@> angleF
        angle = stepper (scaleSpeed initialSpeed) angleSteps <*> time inputs
```

The whole `program` maps `Inputs` to `Outputs`. It says that the behavior for what to `display` is `cubes` lifted and applied to the angle and position. The `Event` for other `IO` side effects is `onReshape` every time the `reshape` event happens.

```
program :: Inputs t -> Outputs t
program inputs = outputs
    where
        outputs = Outputs {
            display = cubes <$> angleB inputs <*> positionB inputs,
            whenIdle = onReshape <$> reshape inputs
        }
```

#### The framework

Our framework accepts a program with the type `forall t. Inputs t -> Outputs t` and runs it. To implement the framework, we use the functions in `Reactive.Banana.Frameworks`. These functions allow us to raise `Event`s from `IO` and run `IO` actions in response to `Event`s. We can make `Behavior`s from `Event`s and poll `Behavior`s when `Event`s occur using the functions from `Reactive.Banana.Combinators`.

```
reactiveGLUT :: (forall t. Inputs t -> Outputs t) -> IO ()
reactiveGLUT program = do
    -- Initial values    
    initialTime <- getCurrentTime
    -- Events
    (addKeyboardMouse, raiseKeyboardMouse) <- newAddHandler
    (addTime, raiseTime) <- newAddHandler
    (addReshape, raiseReshape) <- newAddHandler
    (addDisplay, raiseDisplay) <- newAddHandler
```

`newAddHandler` creates a handle with which to talk about an `Event t a`, and a function to raise the event of type `a -> IO ()`. We make the obvious events for keyboard and mouse input, idle time passing, and the window shape changing. We also make an event that we will use to poll the `display` `Behavior` when we need to run it in the `displayCallback`.

We have one tricky problem to overcome - OpenGL requires all the UI interaction to happen in a specific thread, but we aren't sure what thread the actions we bind to reactive-banana events will happen in. We'll use a couple of variables shared across threads to make sure the `Output` `IO` is run in the OpenGL thread. For `display` output, we'll use an `MVar` to store the polled `display` action. For `IO` actions that are queued in `whenIdle` we'll accumulate them in an `IORef`,

```
    -- output variables and how to write to them
    displayVar <- newEmptyMVar
    whenIdleRef <- newIORef (return ())
    let
        setDisplay = putMVar displayVar
        runDisplay = takeMVar displayVar >>= id
        addWhenIdle y = atomicModifyIORef' whenIdleRef (\x -> (x >> y, ()))
        runWhenIdle = atomicModifyIORef' whenIdleRef (\x -> (return (), x)) >>= id
```

Our whole network consists of the following parts. First we create `Event`s (using `fromAddHandler`) or `Behavior`s (using `fromChanges`) for each of the `Inputs` and an `Event` for polling the output `display`. We perform a small amount of processing to simplify the clock. We apply the `program` to the `inputs` we prepared to get the program's `Outputs`. Using `<@`, we poll the `display` whenever our display event happens. Finally, `reactimate` tells reactive-banana to run `setDisplay` or `addWhenIdle` whenever the corresponsonding `Event` occurs. Once we have described the network we `compile` and `actuate` it.

```
    -- Reactive network for GLUT programs
    let networkDescription  :: forall t. Frameworks t => Moment t ()
        networkDescription  = do
            keyboardMouseEvent <- fromAddHandler addKeyboardMouse
            clock              <- fromChanges initialTime addTime
            reshapeEvent       <- fromAddHandler addReshape
            displayEvent       <- fromAddHandler addDisplay
            let
                diffTime = realToFrac . (flip diffUTCTime) initialTime <$> clock
                inputs = Inputs keyboardMouseEvent diffTime reshapeEvent
                outputs = program inputs
                displayPoll = display outputs <@ displayEvent
            reactimate $ fmap setDisplay displayPoll
            reactimate $ fmap addWhenIdle (whenIdle outputs)
    network <- compile networkDescription
    actuate network
```

For each of the GLUT callbacks we are interested in we raise the corresponding reactive-banana `Event`. For the idle callback we also run any queued events. For the display callback, we run the polled `DisplayCallback`.

```
    -- Handle GLUT events
    keyboardMouseCallback $= Just (\k ks m p -> raiseKeyboardMouse (KeyboardMouse k ks m p))
    idleCallback $= Just (do
        getCurrentTime >>= raiseTime
        runWhenIdle
        postRedisplay Nothing)
    reshapeCallback $= Just raiseReshape
    displayCallback $= do
        raiseDisplay ()
        runDisplay
    mainLoop
```

#### The rest of the example

The rest of the tutorial code can be repeated verbatim

```
vertex3f :: (GLfloat, GLfloat, GLfloat) -> IO ()
vertex3f (x, y, z) = vertex $ Vertex3 x y z    

points :: Int -> [(GLfloat,GLfloat,GLfloat)]
points n = [ (sin (2*pi*k/n'), cos (2*pi*k/n'), 0) | k <- [1..n'] ]
   where n' = fromIntegral n

cube :: GLfloat -> IO ()
cube w = renderPrimitive Quads $ mapM_ vertex3f
  [ ( w, w, w), ( w, w,-w), ( w,-w,-w), ( w,-w, w),
    ( w, w, w), ( w, w,-w), (-w, w,-w), (-w, w, w),
    ( w, w, w), ( w,-w, w), (-w,-w, w), (-w, w, w),
    (-w, w, w), (-w, w,-w), (-w,-w,-w), (-w,-w, w),
    ( w,-w, w), ( w,-w,-w), (-w,-w,-w), (-w,-w, w),
    ( w, w,-w), ( w,-w,-w), (-w,-w,-w), (-w, w,-w) ]
```

Comment: That's a great tutorial for banana. What a pity I could google it when I tried to learn this. (I didn't see it until very late.)

Comment: Just nine upvotes? Pity. Have you considered migrating this answer to the new documentation platform?

Comment: @Cirdec Seems like the `t` parameter has been removed from `Behavior` and `Event`