# In reactive-banana, is it safe to trigger handler actions from multiple threads?

Tags: haskell, frp, reactive-banana

Is it safe to trigger the fire action in

```hs
(addHandler, fire) <- newAddHandler
```

from a different thread from which the reactive-banana graph was compiled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is safe, but there is the caveat that @Cirdec mentioned.

For conreteness, consider the following example that creates an event network using the `addHandler` in a separate thread and then calls `fire` repeatedly in the main thread

```
import Control.Concurrent (myThreadId, threadDelay, forkIO)

main = do
    ...
    (addHandler, fire) <- newAddHandler

    let networkDescription :: MomentIO ()
        networkDescription = do
           e <- fromAddHandler addHandler
           ...
           reactimate $ (print =<< myThreadId) <$ e   -- reactimate

    forkIO $ do
        network <- compile networkDescription
        actuate network
    ...
    forever $ do                                      -- event loop
        threadDelay (10^6)
        fire ()
```

(See the documentation ["Terminating the program" in Control.Concurrent](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#g:12) for why I've put the event loop in the main thread as opposed to putting the network in the main thread.)

In this and similar situations, the following will hold:

- The IO actions executed by the `reactimate` will be run in the thread that calls `fire`, *not* in the thread where the network was compiled. This is what @Cirdec already mentioned.
- If there were a second thread also calling `fire`, then it could potentially interleave with other calls to `fire`, i.e. the program could be calling `fire` twice concurrently. Then,

  - Reactive-banana uses a lock to ensure that Behaviors and Events are updated consistently. You can treat them as pure functions `Time -> a` and lists `[(Time,a)]` as usual.
  - However, the IO actions from the `reactimate`s may interleave. In other words, the pure FRP part will stay pure, but the actual IO is subject to concurrency as usual.

Answer (score 3):

Firing the `fire` handler itself is safe; it reads an `IORef` that is being updated atomically and runs each of the added handlers in the current thread. Whether or not that's safe will depend on what handlers have been added to the `addHandler`.

Using the `addHandler` in `interpretAsHandler`, `fromAddHandler`, or `fromChanges` should be safe. Nothing I know of in reactive-banana has any thread affinity, and even if it did, these are what `newAddHandler` was made for, so it should be safe anyway.

What you need to be careful of is the `IO ()` actions executed by `reactimate`. If you need to reactimate `IO` actions that need to be run in a specific thread (for OpenGL output, etc), you need to only produce `IO ()` actions that will send their data to that thread. In this [complete OpenGL example for reactive-banana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26112094/414413) the `IO ()` actions for OpenGL output, which have thread affinity, are run in the OpenGL thread. Instead of`reactimate`ing the `Event (IO ())` executing them directly they are added to an `IORef`

```
whenIdleRef <- newIORef (return ())
let
    addWhenIdle :: IO () -> IO ()
    addWhenIdle y = atomicModifyIORef' whenIdleRef (\x -> (x >> y, ()))
    runWhenIdle :: IO ()
    runWhenIdle = atomicModifyIORef' whenIdleRef (\x -> (return (), x)) >>= id

let networkDescription  :: forall t. Frameworks t => Moment t ()
    networkDescription  = do

        reactimate $ fmap addWhenIdle (whenIdle outputs)
                     ^                ^
                     |                Event (IO ())
                     Stuff the event into an IORef
```

The `IORef` holding which `IO ()` actions to run is read and each of all the actions are run in a context that I know is in the OpenGL thread.

```
idleCallback $= Just (do           -- will be executed in the OpenGL thread when it's idle
    getCurrentTime >>= raiseTime
    runWhenIdle                    -- run those `IO ()` actions in this thread
    postRedisplay Nothing)
```