# Comparing Functional Reactive Programming packages in Haskell

Tags: haskell, frp

I am new to functional reactive programming and I would like to know how different packages compare in Haskell. They all seem to have slightly different approaches and I don't know enough to choose between them.

I also think that the available information for some of the packages is out of date. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341937/whats-the-status-of-current-functional-reactive-programming-implementations) previous Stack Overflow question recommends either `netwire` or `reactive-banana` but currently `netwire` won't install with `stack` because it depends on an out of date `profunctors` package.

So basically, for a beginner, how do the various FRP packages compare against each other? And which are best for GUI applications and which are best for simulation/game applications?

Thanks,

Comment: I think that's too broad, asking for a off-site resource, is opinion based  _and_ leads to a discussion. You're probably better off at the haskell-cafe mailing list, /r/reddit or other similar sites.

Comment: Is it less broad if I restrict my question to comparing Yampa, netwire, and reactive-banana? Part of the reason I asked this question is the other related questions on this site are a bit out of date (by several years) and I wanted to gather more recent information.

Comment: You should add `reflex` to the list of packages you ask about https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex  https://www.reddit.com/r/reflexfrp/  on irc #reflex-frp , not sure what other things...

Answer (score 3):

I found this link very helpful for comparing FRP libraries.  It gives example code for a simple application written in each library.

https://github.com/gelisam/frp-zoo