# Dynamic event switching in reactive-banana causes severe leak

Tags: haskell, frp, reactive-banana

I'm not sure whether this behavior is expected (i.e. I'm misusing Reactive.Banana.Switch) or a bug.

Let's say I have two like-typed input Behaviors, and I want to switch between them based on an Event.  I wrote this function:

```
switchBehaviors :: 
      Behavior t a -- | Behavior to yield initially and after "True" events
   -> Behavior t a -- | Behavior to yield after "False" events
   -> Event t Bool -- | Select between behaviors
   -> Moment t (Behavior t a)
switchBehaviors t f es = do
    t' <- trimB t
    f' <- trimB f
    return $ switchB t $ (\e -> if e then t' else f') <$> es
```

This code seems innoccuous enough; it type-checks, compiles, and gives the desired result when embedded into a simple GUI mockup.  (Two text entry fields for the Behaviors, a button emitting alternate True and False Events, and a label bound to the combined Behavior using `sink`.)

However, after triggering the Event several times, it becomes obvious that there's a catastropic leak somewhere.  The app starts taking longer and longer to react both to changes in the input Behaviors and to new Events.  It also starts eating memory.

Here's a heap profile with -hC: [image: leaking memory]
I'm repeatedly toggling the Event; the two largest spikes are maybe the twentieth and twenty-first firings of the Event.

The use of trimB feels a bit like hand-waving to make the types add up; I don't know whether I'm using it correctly or abusing it somehow.

My sub-questions are:

1) Am I abusing the Reactive.Banana.Switch API, or is this a bug?  If I am abusing the API, what am I doing wrong?

2) Should I do this without using dynamic event switching?  Using `apply` doesn't give the correct behavior, because the resulting Event doesn't fire when the underlying Behavior changes.  If I unwrap all three inputs to Events, I imagine I can set up a fold, manually accumulating the most recent value of each input Event.  Is that the correct approach?

Comment: Version 0.7 of reactive-banana doesn't implement garbage collection for dynamically switched events yet, so anything very dynamic is likely to eat up space. I'm working on it. :-)

Comment: @HeinrichApfelmus Is this bug still present? I tried an experiment today with dynamic switching (on a key press) and after 10-20 key presses my program became unresponsive and at least once it even crashed with a stack overflow.

Comment: @JasonDagit The development version fixes a few additional space leaks that might contribute to the problem. However, I still haven't come around to implementing garbage collection for dynamic event switching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is actually trivial to implement without dynamic switching, if you use a `Behavior` for the selection input and recall that `Behavior` is an instance of `Applicative`.  I hadn't really internalized the `f <$> x <*> y <*> z ...` idiom when I asked this question, so here's an explicit working-out for others like me:

```
switchBehaviors 
    :: Behavior t a    -- | Behavior to yield when it's "True"
    -> Behavior t a    -- | Behavior to yield when it's "False"
    -> Behavior t Bool -- | Select between behaviors
    -> Behavior t a
switchBehaviors t f es = 
    (\e x y -> if e then x else y) <$> es <*> t <*> f
```

(Heinrich Apfelmus addressed the first question in a comment.  As he notes, `Reactive.Banana.Switch` is still very much experimental, and its performance characteristics are improving.)