# Does push-pull FRP help when implementing games?

Tags: haskell, frp, reactive-banana, netwire

I've been comparing pull-only FRP (ie netwire) with push-pull FRP (ie reactive-bannana) in the implementation of games. Are there advantages to one over the other? Things I've notices are:

- Push events make it easy to have events for mouse clicks / key presses from GLFW or GLUT
- Arrowized FRP that netwire uses has much less `IO` floating around, which is always better.
- It looks like having pull-only responses to things like mouse movement could cause time leaks.

What else have I missed?

Edit, to make this less opinion-based: The main goal is to have something that is as expressive/concise as possible, without time leaks.

**Update:** A big issue I have found with Netwire is that there doesn't seem to be a convenient way to have more than one framerate, as described in the article "Fix your Timestep."

**Update 2:** The way i've gotten around this is to make my game simulation wire return a `Float -> IO ()` that takes the alpha value and does all the GL calls with everything interpolated by that alpha. Ideally I should be able to pass this "draw function" into another thread via an `MVar` and run it in that thread. Man, Haskell is awesome.

**Update 3:** In the six months since asking this question, I developed a [simple rendering engine](https://github.com/danielkeller/H3D) based around Netwire, and the concept of "entity-component programming." In this process I have actually not found the use of FRP to be terribly helpful. The expressiveness of `Wire`s has actually turned out to be a hindrance in some circumstances. The problem centers around the "identity" of objects. When defining a value of `Wire` type, it has no identity, i.e. it may be re-used in the overall network multiple times, and represent different physical things each time. This is a huge pain when you want to do something like collision detection, and have no way to traverse the scene graph, because it cannot exist without being fused into a single opaque wire. This problem does not occur in "toy" examples, because it is easy to [specify exactly](https://github.com/bernstein/breakout/blob/master/src/Main.hs#L99) which properties of which objects interact with which other objects in which ways. I believe this is a problem with either type of FRP.

It would be awesome if some Haskell wizard were to prove me wrong on this, but I don't really see a way around it. Also I'm sorry if the explanation isn't great, but it's not really that easy to understand without trying it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000074/which-frp-package-to-choose) and [there](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Netwire), [Netwire](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/netwire) and [reactive-banana](https://wiki.haskell.org/Reactive-banana) have different purposes and goals. Netwire specialises in modeling framed signals, such as a game server, because what a game server typically does is sending its state to client in periodic frames. Reactive-banana would be the better choice for creating a GUI because a GUI is a purely event-driven model and is not tolerant to time leak.

It seems to me you can use both, depending of which aspect you want to implement.

Comment: Interesting. Are they compatible with each other? I.e., can you transfer information from one to the other?

Comment: After having used netwire in a game engine, I can say that it is excellently suited for that purpose, for the reasons that you stated.